# Uploading mp4 files using PHP

Tags: php, video, upload, mp4

I am able to upload png/jpegs/images using PHP upload script but am not able to upload mp4 files on my local server. Script is not displaying any error.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
//include authentication here/ Gmail is good solution for now
//check if it's not allowing any other extenstion other than MP4
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png","mp4");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
print_r($_FILES["file"]["type"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  } else {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
    if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    } else {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
  }
} else {
  echo "Invalid file";
}
?>
enter code here
changed my code to this


 <?php
    ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting(-1);
    //include authentication here/ Gmail is good solution for now
    //check if it's not allowing any other extenstion other than MP4
    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png","mp4");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    print_r($_FILES["file"]["type"]);
    $extension = end($temp);
    if (($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000)) {
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
      } else {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
        if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
          echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        } else {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
          "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
          echo "Stored in: " . "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        }
      }
    } else {
      echo "Invalid file";
    }
    ?>
```

still same error

> video/mp4Invalid file

Comment: what's the output of your `print_r($_FILES["file"]["type"]);`? not every browser sends the same mime type for the same file.

Comment: Output of print_r($_FILES["file"]["type"]) is video/mp4. No error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code does not have any errors, please make sure to increase post_max_size AND  load_max_filesize AND memory_limit

- [post_max_size](http://php.net/post_max_size)
- [upload_max_filesize](http://php.net/upload_max_filesize)
- [memory_limit](http://php.net/memory_limit)

See [Handling file uploads: Common Pitfals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php) which explains this in detail and how to calculate the values.

Answer (score 2):

you have to modify the POST max size, and the file upload size in your php.ini

It should look like this if you want to disable the limit:

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size=0
```

And of course the file limit:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize=1000M
```