# PHP move_upload_file(); Not Moving to new folder

Tags: php, file, upload, copy, mp4

can anybody see why this code is sucsessfull but the actuall mp4 file is not moves to the folder.. iv sorted all the php.ini files to accept files above 20mg ect. and theres no erros thrown anyway, so the uplaod is sucsessfull and apparently so is the move. But theres no file in the directory after.. I cant think why..

Does this code reveal any reason as to why not.

Also - access is allowed for the dir... o restrictions / permission issues

```
if (!empty($_FILES['sellimage0']['name'])){

if(isset($_POST)){
    if(isset($_FILES['sellimage0'])){
      $errors= array();
      $sellimage0_name = $_FILES['sellimage0']['name'];
      $sellimage0_size =$_FILES['sellimage0']['size'];
      $sellimage0_tmp =$_FILES['sellimage0']['tmp_name'];
      $sellimage0_type=$_FILES['sellimage0']['type'];

//print_r($_FILES['sellimage0']['name']); 

  $sellimage0_ext = pathinfo($_FILES['sellimage0']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

      //$sellimage0_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['sellimage0']['name'])));

      $expensions= array("mp4","ogg","webm");

      if(in_array($sellimage0_ext,$expensions)=== false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a MP4, OGG, or WEBM formats...";
      }

      if($sellimage0_size > 800000000){
         $errors[]='File size must be excately 800 MB';
      }
//print_r($sellimage0_tmp); exit;
      if (move_uploaded_file($sellimage0_tmp,"../images/searchimages/".$sellimage0_name)); {
        $uploadfile="../images/searchimages/".$sellimage0_name;     
        $i0url=$uploadfile;

      if(empty($errors)==true){
        echo $uploadfile;

      }
      else{
         print_r($errors); die();
      }

      }

   }
}


} else {$i0url='';}
```

Comment: Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24362903/uploading-mp4-files-using-php?rq=1) and check if you've edited the `php.ini` with all the variables listed

Comment: Thank you, buit i allready did all this and i still have the issue, the file just is not moved from tmp at all.

Comment: when executing the code you get as result the value from `echo $uploadfile;`?

Comment: yes, the file location where it should be, but its not actually moved there,, go figure.

Comment: there's a typo here: `if (move_uploaded_file($sellimage0_tmp,"../images/searchimages/".$sellimage0_name));`, remove the ; and try again

Comment: still no file in the dir

Comment: $expensions= array("jpg","png","gif","mp4","ogg","webm"); - works with images no problem, but not videos...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174369/discussion-between-signo-and-melissahicking).